# Reducing the number of edges in a pathfinder

Tags: path-finding, graph-theory

I've worked out an algorithm for pathfinding in a quite free-form terrain (not constrained to grids), with the limitation that it doesn't allow the moving character to rotate. I'll use it for AABBs so that's not a problem, and I'll assume AABBs below.

However, one of the steps consists of creating a graph in which the path is to be found, and that's where the problem is: it seems to me that the number of graph edges to construct is going to be O(V²) where V is the number of vertices. Yet when looking at a typical graph, it is apparent that many of these edges do not need any consideration at all. So the question is if there is a way to reduce the number of edges.

The algorithm goes like this. The input is a traveler, a series of boxes (the maze) and a destination point:

http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/rect4572.png

(in this example, the reference point of the traveler is at the bottom right of the rectangle because I made a mistake estimating the MDs by hand; sorry about that)

1. Calculate the Minkowski difference of the traveler and each box in the maze: http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/rect4574.png - this reduces the problem to having a point crossing that maze, simplifying analysis.
2. Create the graph:

   2.1. Each vertex is a corner of one of the boxes in the Minkowski difference.
   2.2. For each pair of vertices, there is an edge iff the line between them does not have any point inside one of the boxes. In other words, if there is a direct line of sight between them.

   Result: http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/rect4758.png (done by hand - I may have forgotten edges)
3. Run a pathfinding algorithm on that graph. http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/rect4776.png

The path found is directly usable in the original map: http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/rect5158.png

The problem is step 2.2. Is it possible to reduce the number of edges?

I'm not aware of any pitfalls in the algorithm, but if you see one, please let me know as well.

Comment: It looks to me like you could convert your Minkowski difference map to a navmesh instead. Chop up the navigable space into convex polygons. Then each border between navigable polygons is node, and all nodes around a single polygon form a clique. No edges that cross polygon boundaries need to be considered.

Comment: @DMGregory That's a good suggestion, thanks! Indeed, triangulating gets rid of many of the edges that are redundant with this algorithm.